# find all $p\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t : $\int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}(\sin(x))^{p} \ln(\sin(x)) \ dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Find all $p\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t : $\displaystyle \int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}(\sin(x))^{p}\ln(\sin(x)) \ dx$ converges.

What I shown so far is that for $p > 0$ the integral converges because $f(x) =\sin(x)^{p} \ln(\sin(x))$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,\pi /2]$ and that the limit as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ exists.

For $p < 0$ I am not sure how to deal with that, I think it diverges but I am not sure how to see that.

It will be great if someone could give me a clue.

Comment: Since the only issue is convergence of the integral near $ x = 0 $, the substitution $ u = \sin(x) $ reveals that this convergence is equivalent to that of $ \int_0^a {u^p \log u \mathrm{d} u} $ (for any small positive $ a $).

Comment: I believe you can demonstrate the following: for all $ p < 0 $, $ |u^p| < |u^p \log u| < |u^{p+\varepsilon}| $ for all $ \varepsilon > 0 $ and $ u $ sufficiently close to $ 0 $.  You can now use your knowledge of convergence of $ \int_0^a {u^p\ \mathrm{d}u} $ to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make $\sin(x)=t$
$$\int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \big[\sin(x)\big]^{p}\log(\sin(x)) \ dx=\int_0^1 \frac{t^p }{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\log (t)\,dt$$ Close to $t=0$
$$\frac{t^p }{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\left(1+\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)\right) t^p\sim t^p$$ and, using integration by parts,
$$\int_0^1 t^p\,\log(t),dt=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2} \qquad \text{if} \qquad \Re(p)>-1$$